# Eliminating an unchecked warning in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, warnings

I am overriding `equals()` for a class I have made.  One type I am expecting is 
`Map<String,String>`

I did the following.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Map<String, String>) {
        return equalsMap((Map<String, String>) o);
    }
```

and got this error:

> Cannot perform instanceof check against parameterized type `Map<String,String>`. Use the form `Map<?,?>` instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime

so I changed it to the following, which it took:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
        return equalsMap((Map<String, String>) o);
    }
```

(The first one has the `@Override` in it too but I forgot to copy it in and now it won't let me).

When I did the above It compiles but now I get this warning with no suggestions:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to `Map<String,String>`

I can understand that it could be anything in the `Map<?,?>` but I tried above to make it more specific and it gave me the error and told me to use  so I am not sure what to do.  All it suggests is to use `SuppressWarnings 'unchecked'` (I cannot type the at sign here without getting an error) which is I guess OK but I would rather not have a warning to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want a warning, the only solution is going to be

```
if (o instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
    return equalsMap((Map<?, ?>) o);
}
```

and to make your `equalsMap` method do the right thing for arbitrary `Map` types.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing:

`public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
   boolean isString = false;
   Map<?, ?> map = (Map<?, ?>) o;
   for (Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if ((entry.getKey() instanceof String) && entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
     isString = true;
    }
    break; // fall through
   }
   if (isString) {
    return equalsMap((Map<String, String>) o);
   }
  }`


and it falls through to call the default otherwise.  Hope this is OK?

Comment: You could do that, but there's not likely to be any point.  What is the body of `equalsMap`, and are you so sure that it won't work correctly on an arbitrary `Map`?

Comment: I can show the body, or at least part of it, but the formatting will be horrible ;-(.  I have to cut out part that is probably company confidential

Comment: public Boolean equalsMap(Map<String, String> map) {
        ...
  if {(!rdb(getStreetAddress1()).equals(rdb(map.get("AddressLine1")))) {
   return logError(map, "Address line 1 expected " + getStreetAddress1() + " but got " + map.get(
     "AddressLine1"));
  }
 
  String csz = rdb(map.get("City") + ", " + map.get("stateAbbreviation") + " " + map.get("Zipcode"));
  if (!ds(getCityStateZip5()).equals(csz)) {
   return logError(map, "City state and zip expected " + ds(getCityStateZip() + " but got " + csz));
  }
...
...

Comment: rdb() simply removes duplicate blanks